# Запретить изменение текста в ComboBox JavaFX

Tags: javafx, combobox, prompt

Здравствуйте. Как сделать, чтобы ComboBox не изменял значение, когда юзер выбирает какое-либо значение? То есть всегда показывался только prompt текст

//UPD: это можно сделать, но далее мне понадобилось отловить, что пользователь несколько раз нажимал на одно значение и тут начались трудности. Начались они потому что я использовал ComboBox в качестве меню, где пользователь выбирал значение и от этого происходило действие, а это неправильно, потому что ComboBox создан для того, чтобы давать пользователю просто выбрать элемент. Так что если у вас та же нужда, что у меня присмотритесь к MenuButton. Выглядят они одинаково

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;

public class PromptListCell<T> extends ListCell<T> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if ( getParent() instanceof ComboBox ) {
            ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) getParent();
            setText(comboBox.getPromptText());
        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования

```
comboBox.setButtonCell(new PromptListCell<>());
```